# How to map two Google Custom Domain with two Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two app engine (default & app2), So, when I added a custom domain from **app engine -> settings -> custom domain** section, it will map automatically with the default app engine, but I want to map that custom domain with my app2 app-engine only.

So, Can you guide how to figure out the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the custom domains that you need from that page, and then use the [Dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) to specify which App Engine service you would like to listen at that URL.

```
dispatch:
  - url: <DOMAIN>/*     # for example: subdomain.example.com/*
    service: <SERVICE-NAME>   # for example: app2
```

Deploy it using: gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml --project

Comment: So, now my app-engine running on http://app2.domain.com and as well as https://app2.domain.com. Both are opening same app engine. Now how I fix the url redirection to https from http. it should open in only https.

Comment: As mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements

You just have to add these two words to your app.yaml file under the appropriate url entry:
secure: always

For example:

- url: .*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
Then if a user tries to access the URL with HTTP she will be automatically redirected to HTTPS. Pretty cool.